# Clarification on a website security

Tags: web-application, web-browser, vulnerability

I am new to work on website handling and here are my questions.

1) How can I ensure that the pages accessing is secure enough for data transmission , sql injection and several other attacks.

2) How can I ensure the page which am working on is the original page?

3) Sometimes I am seeing that my browsers restrict me to click or proceed on some of the internal links ? why this happening ?

4) Sometimes the pages get auto refreshed if I am idle for few minutes, in this situation can someone do by pass-by sessions ?

5) How can I ensure that the form submitted to the server is proper and no one has altered it?

Comment: There are a lot of different questions here. Can you split them up into separate, but related questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to help you with some of them.

> How can I ensure that the pages accessing is secure enough for data
>   transmission , sql injection and several other attacks.

For data transmission you should use **HTTPS**, avoiding attacks between client and server. 
Security concern **should be addressed** when developing the application, choosing a programming language or framework that is capable of implementing CSRF protection, sanitizing HTTP request data avoiding SQL Injection and XSS, and forcing you to use the best practices.

You should be aware that security **need to be envolved in all steps** when developing your application.

> How can I ensure the page which am working on is the original page?

You could Hash the page, or use some type of [version control](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)(when developing).

> Sometimes the pages get auto refreshed if I am idle for few minutes,
>   in this situation can someone do by pass-by sessions ?

No, this is most likely implemented by the application to keep the page updated, using [HTTP-EQUIV REFRESH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

> How can I ensure that the form submitted to the server is proper and
>   no one has altered it?

Again, you should use HTTPS to avoid any concern with tampering or sniifing between client and server communication. Plus, like mentioned before, CSRF protection would avoid having this form submitted without user approval or knowledge about the content.